# Url Changing to seo friendly

Tags: magento-2.3

I want to change [www.m2.com/authors/view/index/id/1](http://www.m2.com/authors/view/index/id/1) to [www.m2.com/authors/author_name.html](http://www.m2.com/authors/author_name.html) how can i achieve this?
help

Comment: did you try out https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-change-cms-pages-and-system-pages-url-aliases.html

Comment: i want to achieve programmatically. im a beginner to magento plz explain